# How to add missing years in panel dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My toy DataFrame is similar to

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'year': [1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
                 1999, 2000, 2003, 2004, 2005],
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200, 300, 400, 120, 
                  140, 150, 155, 156]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What's the most elegant way to add missing years?
In the example, the years 2001 and 2002 are missing for `id = 2` because of missing data. In such cases, I still want to have the years in the DataFrame, id should be 2 and `price = NaN`.

My real DataFrame has thousands of IDs.

Comment: Depending on your data, you can try `df.pivot('id', 'year', 'price').stack(dropna=False).rename('price').reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross `merge` to create all possible combinations of "Year" and "ID" and `merge` back to the original DataFrame:

```
>>> df["year"].drop_duplicates().to_frame().merge(df["id"].drop_duplicates(), how="cross").merge(df, how="left")
    year  id   price
0   1999   1  1200.0
1   1999   2   120.0
2   2000   1   150.0
3   2000   2   140.0
4   2001   1   300.0
5   2001   2     NaN
6   2002   1   450.0
7   2002   2     NaN
8   2003   1   200.0
9   2003   2   150.0
10  2004   1   300.0
11  2004   2   155.0
12  2005   1   400.0
13  2005   2   156.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
You can also use `product` from `itertools`:

```
# from itertools import product

>>> df.set_index(['year', 'id']).reindex(product(set(df['year']), set(df['id']))) \
      .sort_index(level=1).reset_index()

    year  id   price
0   1999   1  1200.0
1   2000   1   150.0
2   2001   1   300.0
3   2002   1   450.0
4   2003   1   200.0
5   2004   1   300.0
6   2005   1   400.0
7   1999   2   120.0
8   2000   2   140.0
9   2001   2     NaN
10  2002   2     NaN
11  2003   2   150.0
12  2004   2   155.0
13  2005   2   156.0
```

Create a `MultiIndex` of all combinations of `year` and `id` columns. Set this columns as index and reindex by the multi-index:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['year'].unique(), df['id'].unique()], names=['year', 'id'])

out = df.set_index(['year', 'id']).reindex(mi).reset_index().sort_values('id', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    year  id   price
0   1999   1  1200.0
1   2000   1   150.0
2   2001   1   300.0
3   2002   1   450.0
4   2003   1   200.0
5   2004   1   300.0
6   2005   1   400.0
7   1999   2   120.0
8   2000   2   140.0
9   2001   2     NaN
10  2002   2     NaN
11  2003   2   150.0
12  2004   2   155.0
13  2005   2   156.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make "year" a Categorical variable and include it in the `groupby`:

```
df['year'] = pd.Categorical(df['year'], categories=df['year'].unique())
out = df.groupby(['id', 'year'], as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
    id  year   price
0    1  1999  1200.0
1    1  2000   150.0
2    1  2001   300.0
3    1  2002   450.0
4    1  2003   200.0
5    1  2004   300.0
6    1  2005   400.0
7    2  1999   120.0
8    2  2000   140.0
9    2  2001     NaN
10   2  2002     NaN
11   2  2003   150.0
12   2  2004   155.0
13   2  2005   156.0
```